# Why would my wife's MacBook Pro start up as soon as I touch the keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, power-management

My son just spilled milk on the keyboard of my wife's MacBook Pro.  This is definitely a time to cry, because of the risk of liquid getting into the electronics of the computer.  I immediately held the power button down to turn it off, and ! it just rebooted.

I used used software to shut it down, but as soon as I started to wipe down the keyboard  the thing just rebooted again.  WHAT ON EARTH!?  Is there a setting that causes Macs to start as soon as any key is touched?  Or is this a sign that the milk has made some connection that I don't want to have been made?

She has a recent-ish model with the touchbar, in case they behave differently.

Comment: In sleep mode any key can wake them but depends on sys prefs. However, get it cleaned properly and quick as damage or corrosion can be fatal. Then keep it away from liquids.

Comment: @SolarMike but I specifically chose "Shut Down" from the menu...